# K-connectivity reflective, symmetric, transitive

Tags: data-structures, graph-theory

I have to prove the following:

In a directed graph if there are k distinct paths (which don't use the same edges) from vector x to y and also there are k distinct paths(which don't use the same edges) from vector y to x
we symbolize it like this: x ≡ y and we call them k-connected vectors.

I have to prove that this relation is reflective, symmetric, and transitive.

Also, does anything change if the paths use distinct vectors and edge all together?

Comment: is your graph undirected?

Comment: @NimaAfshar The graph is directed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation) property:

  If you consider *k* the number of distinct (not using the same edges) loops containing node *x*, then for every *x*, we have some *k* that holds *x* ≡ *x*.
- [Symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) property:

  (*x* ≡ *y*) means:

  (there are *k* distinct paths from *x* to *y*.) **and** (there are *k* distinct paths from *y* to *x*.)

  (*y* ≡ *x*) means:

  (there are *k* distinct paths from *y* to *x*.) **and** (there are *k* distinct paths from *x* to *y*.)

  So because of the symmetry of [Logical Conjuction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction), (*x* ≡ *y*) implies (*y* ≡ *x*) and vice versa.
- [Transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) property:

  Suppose we have (*x* ≡ *y*) and (*y* ≡ *x*)

  the first implies that (there are *k* distinct paths from *x* to *y*; we name them `a_1` to `a_k` in arbitrary order) **and** (there are *k* distinct paths from *y* to *x*; we name them `a'_1` to `a'_k`).

  the second implies that (there are *k* distinct paths from *y* to *z*; we name them `b_1` to `b_k` in arbitrary order) **and** (there are *k* distinct paths from *z* to *y*; we name them `b'_1` to `b'_k`).

  we can construct `c_1` from concatenating `a_1` and `b_1` because `a_1` ends at *y* and `b_1` starts at *y*. so `c_1` is a path from *x* to *z*. this way we can build `c_2` to `c_k` too. for any *i* and *j*, `c_i` and `c_j` don't have same edges, because their parts (`a_i` and `a_j` and `b_i` and `b_j`) don't share the same edges. so there are *k* distinct paths from *x* to *z*.

  the same way we can construct `c'_1` to `c'_k` from `a'_1` to `a'_k` and `b'_1` to `b'_k`. so there are *k* distinct paths from *z* to *x*.

  So we can imply that (*x* ≡ *z*).

The proof holds if paths don't share vectors too. Because that implies, they don't share edges which is an assumption for this proof.